# SQL Server CAST from varchar to numeric fails with error

Tags: sql-server, casting

I have a column of data that contains 9 digits of numeric values, but the column is defined as a varchar. I need to CAST the field to a numeric value so I can divide the sum of the column by 100. e.g.

```
select CAST(field1 as numeric(9,2)) / 100 from table;
```

I get the following error when running the query: Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

If I perform a double CAST from varchar -> int -> numeric, the CAST works. e.g.

```
select CAST(CAST(field1 as int) as numeric(9,2)) / 100 from table;
```

Is there a reason why the single CAST from varchar -> numeric results in a SQL error, but the double CAST works?

Comment: What is the **value** of your `field1` that you're trying to convert?? NUMERIC(9,2) will have only 7 digits before the decimal point - so anything larger than 10 million **will** cause a numeric overflow....

Comment: Most of the values in the field are 0000xxxxx, where there are 3-4 leading zero's. There are no decimal values in the field before the CAST.

Answer (score 6):

If your field contains 9 digits, it could be a max of `999,999,999`. My original thought was that your cast should be `CAST (NUMERIC 11, 2)`

**edit**

To be on the safe side, with 9 character length, you could have numbers ranging from `999,999,999` to `0.1234567`. This means you need 9 digits before the decimal point and 7 after (total 16). Therefore your cast should be `CAST (NUMERIC (16,7)`

`select CAST(field1  as numeric(16,7) from table;`

Comment: No luck with expanding the field length to (11,2). I still get the arithmetic overflow error.

Comment: I just saw the exanded field values, no luck with numeric(19,8) either.

Comment: Can you post the value that is causing the arithmetic overflow?

Comment: Thanks Raj, you pointed me in the right direction. There was one field that had just '-' in it that we missed in our analysis. CASTing '-' is what gave us the arithmetic overflow.

Answer (score 3):

The cause of the error was one row that had '-' as the value for the field. CASTing directly to NUMERIC doesn't work, but CASTing to INT first forced the '-' fields to return 0.

Comment: We found this article helpful (after the fact) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx  We tried using the isNumeric() function to validate our data, but the minus sign, '-', returns a false positive.

Comment: Thanks for the hint regarding the '-' symbol.  It has helped me solve a similar problem.